# Swift and (very) large integers

Tags: prime-numbers

I am trying to write a simple Mac program to factor primes. Nothing new, but I have a problem. The largest integer I can use seems to be 2^64, which is not that big.

Did you hit any similar problem? If so, how did you solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The more common terminology is a BigNum library...

Comment: Factoring primes is pretty easy...

Comment: An excellent  option for educational purposes is Python, which long type has no size limitation, and is available for free on all major platforms.

Comment: @fkraiem: the overall idea is to use simple problems to learn a new language

Comment: @fgrieu:python is good, but I don't like it at all. It is a very long discussion, that goes beyond technicalities. But I really appreciate your input.

Comment: With Swift as the first word of the title, and no reference to crypto, the question is off-topic. If logic prevails, it will eventually get closed (the confusion between factoring primes and factoring _into_ primes, and lack of the [tag:factoring] tag will only help). Things would be different with a more generic question, making reference to Swift as an illustration of the language considered (something compiled without support for large integers).

Answer (score 5):

Language and platform-specific considerations are out-of-scope here, as well as anything not crypto-related. Thus my answer will cover generic issues implementing large-integer arithmetic for cryptographic purposes.

The elementary issue is stated in the question: many languages do not directly support variables larger than 64-bit. The straightforward solution to *that* issue is using a language without such limitation (like Python, GP/Pari, Mathematica), or for other languages implementing the algorithms taught in elementary school for manual computation in decimal, using the language's arithmetic. Any Turing-complete language allows that. Coding such "bignum" library is a very good exercise in programming (and in a few languages like C++ which allow to overload arithmetic operators like `+` `-` `*` `/` `%`, simple expressions can even keep a natural look). If coded very carefully, that can be extended to bases larger than 10 (like 16=2<sup>4</sup>, 2<sup>8</sup>, 2<sup>16</sup>, 2<sup>32</sup>..) to improve performance.

Unfortunately, all the above approaches

- Tend to have execution time that depends on the value of the integers manipulated, which is a very serious issue in many cryptographic application due to timing attacks (including for encryption, decryption, and generating a signature). While it might be possible to live with data-dependent timing using workarounds like blinding (as performed in some Java crypto libraries including Bouncy Castle), that's brittle. Ideally, a bignum library should be written from the grounds up to avoid data-dependent timing. That's hard, but [BearSSL](https://bearssl.org/) shows it's within human reach (he's not really a bear).
- Tend to have other side-channel issues. Given the pace at which new CPU-specific side-channel attacks burgeon lately, there seems to be no robust solution on modern high-performance CPUs other than ensuring adversaries can't run code on the same CPU, or using a dedicated CPU like a Smart Card or HSM.
- Typically are limited to performance well below what careful assembly language allows. That's often by a factor >1000 for naive implementations using decimal internally, >3 with some level of care in the choice of base and algorithms (some languages with built-in support for large integers are exceptions; Java was not last time I checked, which is years ago). Among several reasons, few compilers emit the CPU instructions that access the result of a multiplication to its full width, which is double of its argument; that forces to internally use a base half as large as desirable. The only counterexamples I know involve using Compiler Intrinsics, which is a way to perform assembly from a high-level language with moderate performance loss.

For secure crypto applications manipulating secret data (which is most except signature checking and cryptanalysis, including factoring), coding an efficient bignum package is a very difficult task, requiring a lot of specialized expertise. It's much more reasonable to use a library function on a CPU kept out of reach of adversaries, or dedicated hardware.

When security is not an issue, but speed is, use of a standard library is the straightforward way to go. [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) is probably the first to consider.

---

For fast computer arithmetic, a useful reference is Richard P. Brent and Paul Zimmermann's [*Modern Computer Arithmetic*](https://members.loria.fr/PZimmermann/mca/mca-cup-0.5.9.pdf), published by [Cambridge University Press](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/mathematics/computational-science/modern-computer-arithmetic?format=HB&isbn=9780521194693), 2010.

Somewhat dated, but simpler and more focused on cryptography: Alfred J. Menezes, Paul C. van Oorschot and Scott A. Vanstone's [*Handbook of Applied Cryptography*](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), [chapter 14](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf), published by [CRC Press](https://www.crcpress.com/Handbook-of-Applied-Cryptography/Menezes-Katz-van-Oorschot-Vanstone/p/book/9780849385230), 1996.

Neither of these reference focus on constant-timeness. For this with decent speed, the underlying hardware first needs to be carefully analyzed, [as did BearSSL](https://bearssl.org/ctmul.html).

Comment: Later Java versions have intrinsics to speed up `BigInteger` operations, replacing Java's byte code instructions with native instructions. I've always understood that those ops have been designed mainly for implementations within `java.security` but I haven't evaluated the security of said ops myself.

Comment: For computing with Prime Numbers, I have found [Crandall and Pomerance](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387252827) very useful.

Comment: @rossum: it is an excellent reference to study primality testing/search and factorization algorithms, using a language or library capable of handling large integers. I do not remember that it discuss implementation of that, and I would have noticed if it was geared towards resiting timing or other side-channel attacks.